# How to use "if"?

Tags: grammar

> Next time, if you chance to visit Tainan, home to Tu Hsiao Yuel, be sure to give it a try.

My first question is why the sentence is "if you chance to..." rather than "if you have a chance to...". I think there are no "verb" in the former sentence.

My second question : Is the sentence ",home to" equal to ",which is home to"?

Answer (score 1):

The usage ***if you chance to*** is at the very least "dated" - bordering on "archaic", imho<sup>1</sup>. We'd nearly always use ***happen*** today...

[[image]

OP is misparsing the usage if he supposes it's a cut-down version of *if you **have a** chance to [do something]*. The word ***chance*** here is essentially a *verb*, not a noun. Consider this chart including auxiliary ***should***, with *exactly the same meaning*...

[image]

That's to say ***to chance to [do X]*** = **to happen to do X** (in contexts where "doing X" is thought to be *an **unlikely** future action, but it **might** happen / come to pass*). Thus, *if you chance to visit Tainan* is equivalent to saying *if you visit Tainan*, but with the added implication that the speaker doesn't think it's very likely that you will in fact do so (and *usually* with the additional implication that it would be *fortuitous* if you did in fact visit).

---

The "compound noun phrase" ***Tainan, home to Tu Hsiao Yuel*** is a reduced version of *Tainan, **which is** home to Tu Hsiao Yuel* - where the "base" noun is ***Tainan***, modified by the relative clause *[which is] home to Tu Hsiao Yuel*, within which ***which is*** is effectively optional.

---

<sup>1</sup> Perhaps "archaic" is a bit strong (see [@MichaelHarvey's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/188449/how-to-use-if/188453?noredirect=1#comment371891_188453) below). But my basic point still stands - it might be worth (advanced) learners being aware that the usage does still occur "naturally" with some native speakers, but it's not really something you'd normally want to incorporate into your own speech patterns as a non-native speaker.

Comment: "If you chance to [do something]" has not entirely fallen out of use; I and the people I mix with use it reasonably often, to mean "if you should happen to do something", for example "If you chance to see Joe Smith in the next few days, ask him if his car is still for sale".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, I'm certainly not going to argue with you if you say you often hear people saying it. But I can't help noticing that you only claim that ***other people*** use it. What about you yourself? Do you really use ***chance*** "naturally" in such contexts? I'd have to say that both my own gut feel and those two charts are pretty strong evidence that it's a dying/dead usage (especially in ***speech***, where emerging usage trends are always underrepresented in charts of ***written*** instances).

Comment: ...it's really a matter of opinion, but personally I wouldn't advise *learners* to reproduce usages like this in their own speech (or indeed writing, no matter *how* "formal, poetic" they might wish to sound).

Comment: My comment says "**I and the people I mix with** use it reasonably often", my milieu is mainly lower and middle middle-class people, etc, aged between about 20 and 80, all over England, Scotland, and Wales. I promise you it is by no means archaic or outlandish. With all due respect, gut feelings, backed up by Google N-grams or not, are by no means reliable guides to usage. In any case, N-grams are obtained by indexing books. I am talking about speech mainly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, this may simply be a dialectical divide.  I can't recall ever hearing, in the various regions of the United States I've lived, anyone say "if you chance to ___."  At least not unironically.  I would think it's reasonable to assume that this usage of "chance" is quite unusual in American English.  Perhaps it's still current in British English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: In that case we really do have a difference of opinion. I'm quite convinced that there would be at least *some* people who might still tend to use ***chance*** in this way in a formal written context, even though they'd be very unlikely to use it in casual speech. I'm not saying I'd necessarily think "That was a dated / quaint way of putting it" if I heard a native speaker come out with your *If you chance to see Joe* example (dated usages often survive in "pockets"), but I might well flag it up with a nns who genuinely wanted to be idiomatically "current".

Comment: @Juhasz: Checking the AmE/BrE corpuses for my two charts, I must admit there's *some* suggestion that ***chance*** has retained a little more currency on our (mine & Michael's) side of the pond. But it's very much a "minority" usage everywhere, so from a learner's point of view it's only really worth being aware that the usage does/did exist - not something it's worth including in one's "productive" vocabulary.

Comment: "If you chance to meet a desert tortoise (or if you’re even luckier and find any silver-dollar-sized baby tortoises) along the way, take a moment to thank it for this conservation area’s existence." - Red Cliffs Desert Reserve, Utah.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am not some yokel stuck in a dialect "pocket". I am an RP-speaking Londoner who has lived in Bristol for 50 years and work in the justice system.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Well, I've edited my answer to acknowledge that there might not be universal agreement on this matter, just in case the mods decide to "tidy away" our comments here (I'm guessing they'd never do that for your *first* comment, now that I've actually included a link to it! :)

Comment: I never meant to imply "dialectal yokel". In linguistic contexts, "pockets" could be quite rarefied (royalty, for example, might be referenced as a "linguistic pocket" in some context).